# Change route path without reloading controller and template in angularjs route

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Hi all angularjs developer, I have followed the ng document ([link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)) .I have searched since many times but i did not find any solution that will help me properly. I need to change route without reloading the controller and template. I have written a route that look like this below:-

```
             $routeProvider
             .when('/page1', {
                 templateUrl: 'page1',
                 controller: 'page1Ctrl',
                 caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
                 reloadOnSearch: false
             })
             .when('/page2', {
                 templateUrl: 'page2',
                 controller: 'page2Ctrl',
                 caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
                 reloadOnSearch: false
             })
            .when('/page3', {
                templateUrl: 'page3',
                controller: 'page3Ctrl',
                caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
                reloadOnSearch: false
            }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/index' });
```

Moreover, at first I go to the page1 then page2 then page3 after that now i want to go to the page1 without reloading or calling page1Ctrl and page1 template. Example: suppose when i was page1 that time i have worked something like i have selected an ng-grid record which was paging size 3 and i have inputted some fields. After that i go the page3 then i go to the page1 again. Now this time i want to see the page1 what i selected ng grid record and what i inputted. How can i solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest to use Angular [Ui.router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

you will have the ability to change the state of routes , for more check the documentation

Comment: Thanks @Narek Mamikonyan. I will try this. but do you have any example for this type of work?

Comment: If you will check the doc I think you'll find it :)

Comment: Ok @Narek Mamikonyan.

Comment: Hi @Narek Mamikonyan, I have not seen any information that will help me.

Comment: There has an "Absolute Routes (^)". This absolute route does not work.

Answer (score 0):

To persist data when moving away from a controller and then back again, the recommended Angular approach is to use services. See this NG-Conf talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62RvRQuMVyg.

To persist input fields and paging index when leaving page1Ctrl and then returning, for example, you could create a pagingModelService.

```
function PagingModelService($rootScope)
{
   var pagingModelService = {};

   ////////////////////
   // persisted data //
   ////////////////////
   pagingModelService.pagingIndex;
   pagingModelService.field1;
   pagingModelService.field2;

   ////////
   //Init//
   ////////
   return(pagingModelService);

}
```

Then inject the service in the controller, and set the $scope values to the service:

```
function Page1Ctrl($scope, pagingModelServiceModel)
{
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
   //set local $scope variables to persisted service//
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
   $scope.pageIndex = pagingModelService.pagingIndex;
   $scope.field1 = pagingModelService.field1;
   $scope.field2 = pagingModelService.field2;
}
```

Also, you can look into angular-local-storage for persisting data: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Comment: Thanks for your good concepts @Scott Rice. But I want to manage from route without creating service or factory.